# Why does abline shows on the opposite side on kernel density plots?

Tags: r

I'm curious why the vertical line is showing at -10 and not 10 in the following example:

```
x <- rnorm(1e4, 0, 10)
plot(density(x))
abline(10, 1, col = "red")
```

Comment: In fact you aren't plotting a vertical line but a 1-sloped one  with a intercept of 10 (thus crossing the x axis at -10). It is not appreciable because the y axis has a very small scale respect to x axis.

Comment: You can see it if you change `ylim=`: `plot(density(x), ylim=c(-10, 10)); abline(10, 1, col = "red"); abline(v=0, lty=3)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is using `h=10` instead of `a=10, b=1`. From the helpfile you can read:

> `h` the x-value(s) for vertical line(s).

So, to produce your desired output use the following:

```
abline(v=10, col = "red")
```

[image]